# Relational API: where() can not determine the column using namespaced classes

Tags: php, namespaces, propel

Im trying to do something like this

> $u = \Entity\UserQuery::create()->where('User.Username = ?', "john")->findOne();

but I get this error

> Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause 'User.Username = ?'

While the same code in a non-namespaced context works fine.

I known that there are better ways to do it, but I want to known why this fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well-known problem:

- https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/87
- https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/137

The best way to solve your problem is to use an alias:

```
$u = \Entity\UserQuery::create('alias')
    ->where('alias.Username = ?', "john")
    ->findOne();
```

The following code should work as well:

```
$u = \Entity\UserQuery::create('alias')
    ->where('Entity\UserQuery.Username = ?', "john") // or ->where('\Entity\UserQuery.Username = ?', "john")
    ->findOne();
```

Regards,
William

Comment: I'm curious as to why you used the relational API instead of the ActiveQuery class, i.e. a mere `\Entity\UserQuery::create()->filterByUserName('john')->findOne()` would have surficed since this is a simple query without any joins, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying the 3rd parameter, binding type, helped me:

```
$u = \Entity\UserQuery::create()
    ->where('alias.Username = ?', "john", \PDO::PARAM_STR)
    ->findOne();
```